# An unfair three-sided die.

Tags: probability

An unfair three-sided die. Side $1$ will be rolled with probability $p_1$ , Side $2$ with probability $p_ 2$ and
Side $3$ with probability $p_ 3$ . Find a formula for the probability that the $8^{th}$ $3$ will be rolled on the $10^{th}$
roll.

Attempt: 
First 9 rolls there are 7 three's. 
$$[\binom{9}{7}(p_3)^7(p_1+p_2)^2]\cdot p_3$$
$$=[84\cdot(p_3)^7(p_1+p_2)^2]\cdot p_3$$

any thoughts of this solution?

Comment: ${9\choose7}={9\cdot8\over2}=36$  Otherwise, it looks right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Attempt: First 9 rolls there are 7 three's.
>   $$\left[\binom 97 (p_3)^7(p_1+p_2)^2\right]\cdot p_3$$

Very good to this point, although as sailspatz commented, you had an incorrect evaluation for that binomial.

You can also simplify to: $$ 36\,(p_3)^8\,(1-p_3)^2$$